# Should Foreign Keys have corresponding getters and setters in Room Persistence Library?

Tags: java, android, android-room

The following code shows that I have created an entity with the class name `UserGeneral`. Each of the columns unique to this entity have corresponding getters and setters. However, the foreign keys have no getters and setters. **Do I need to provide getters and setters for `user_details_id` and `user_location_id`?**

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "User_General",
    indices = {
        @Index("user_details_id"),
        @Index("user_location_id")
    },
    foreignKeys = {
        @ForeignKey(
            entity = UserDetails.class,
            parentColumns = "user_details_id",
            childColumns = "user_details_id"
        ),
        @ForeignKey(
            entity = UserLocation.class,
            parentColumns = "user_location_id",
            childColumns = "user_location_id"
        )
    }
)
public class UserGeneral {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_general_id")
    private int user_general_id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name")
    private String first_name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name")
    private String last_name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "flagged_delete")
    private boolean flagged_delete;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_details_id")
    private int user_details_id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_location_id")
    private int user_location_id;


    public int getUser_general_id() {
        return user_general_id;
    }

    public void setUser_general_id(int user_general_id) {
        this.user_general_id = user_general_id;
    }

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public boolean isFlagged_delete() {
        return flagged_delete;
    }

    public void setFlagged_delete(boolean flagged_delete) {
        this.flagged_delete = flagged_delete;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide getter otherwise you will get something like:

```
error: Cannot find getter for field.
    private int user_details_id;
```

setters or passing argument in constructor is used by you. If you don't have such methods then you won't be able to **correctly** initialize the object. In your case without setters / constructor user_details_id would always be 0 (the same goes for your other foreign key), so all your UserGeneral entities would point to the same user details / location.